# jQuery JSON SyntaxError: JSON.parse only on FIREFOX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firefox

Hi Guys the problem is simple but I can't resolve it - it happen only in FIREFOX here is code:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: validUrl,
     data: serializedForm,
     beforeSend: function(x) {
      if(x && x.overrideMimeType) {
       x.overrideMimeType(jsonMimeType);
      }
     },
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(resp){

        console.log(resp);
        var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);
     }
    });
```

console.log give such answer:

> ["emailAddress.used", "register.confirmRulesError"]

I have error in:

> var arr = jQuery.parseJSON(resp);

Full error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

This happens only in FireFox and I can't find solution.

Response header is: Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try without parse json you data.because,

response data look like this,

```
 ["emailAddress.used", "register.confirmRulesError"]
```

if you tring to parse,need key,value pair in json,that is reason it thorw exception.

```
{["emailAddress.used", "register.confirmRulesError"]}//not allowed.
```